# facebook like always reset to 0

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I have a problem with Facebook like button that resets to 0. 
For example you can see it in this [url](http://brooklyn.lodgify.com).

It should have a Facebook like count of 1 but it shows 0. 
This used to work and it recently stopped.
We are using `socialite.js` plugin.

We are at a loss on how to fix this. Any idea?

To make things stranger sometimes the number shows correctly without us changing anything.. and then it goes back to 0 again.

Comment: http://brooklyn.lodgify.com/en shows 1 like, http://brooklyn.lodgify.com/de shows 0 – seems correct, and corresponds with what the Graph API shows. If you want all likes to be counted for the same “version”, and not individually – then set the `og:url` meta info explicitly.

Comment: Hi @CBroe to me brooklyn.lodgify.com/en shows 0 likes (if I'm logged in or not is the same). Also all the likes go to brooklyn.lodgify.com by this setting of the socialite plugin: data-href="http://brooklyn.lodgify.com".

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem was that the url receiving the likes was returning a 301 and not a 200. So no matter what is set in og:url facebook gives inconsistent results.

We had to change the url redirection policy of our site in order to serve the url that receive the likes without redirection and it now works.